# Javascript object map calculate the count of keys with values in a certain range

Tags: javascript

My problem is that I want to create a new object containing the count of keys with a values in a certain range . I think the best way for me to articulate this problem is by illustrating it as follows.

My dataset is as follows:

a = a sequence of ordered numbers from 1-1000 like an id/row number

b = any random number between 1-100

```
{"a":1,"b":59},
{"a":2,"b":88},
{"a":3,"b":69},
{"a":4,"b":28},
{"a":5,"b":75},
{"a":6,"b":78}
...]
```

Now I want to create an algorithm that calculates the number of a's (row numbers) with a frequency(b) in the range of e.g: 0-9 and put that value into a new object which would ideally look something like

with c representing that range(0-9, 1-19, 20-29...90-100)

and d representing the count of id's(a) with a frequency(b) in range(c)

```
[
{"c":1, "d":10},
{"c":2, "d":13},
{"c":3, "d":20},
...
{"c":10, "d":6}
]
```

I have tried a few different things without getting the desired result. I also need to put the result of that count into a new object Map which I am unsure how to do.

```
dat = [
  { "ruid": 1, "id_frequency": 5 },
  { "ruid": 2, "id_frequency": 88 },
  { "ruid": 3, "id_frequency": 69 },
  { "ruid": 4, "id_frequency": 28 },
  { "ruid": 5, "id_frequency": 75 },
  { "ruid": 6, "id_frequency": 78 },
  { "ruid": 7, "id_frequency": 18 },
  { "ruid": 8, "id_frequency": 90 },
  { "ruid": 9, "id_frequency": 22 }
];

var freq = Object.keys(dat).filter(function(key){
   return ( dat[key] > 0 && dat[key] <10 );
}).length;
```

Comment: I don't see a question. I simply see "Now I want to create an algorithm...". Could you provide what you've tried and edit your *question* with a *question*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take an array and the integer value of a tenth of the value as index for counting.

```js
var data = [{ a: 1, b: 59 }, { a: 2, b: 88 }, { a: 3, b: 69 }, { a: 4, b: 28 }, { a: 5, b: 75 }, { a: 6, b: 78 }],
    result = data
        .reduce((r, { b }) => {
            r[Math.floor(b / 10)].d++;
            return r;    
        }, Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => ({ c: i + 1, d: 0})))


console.log(result);
```